# Fetch API: Using the a Request object

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, fetch-api

I’m trying to get a solid understanding of the JavaScript Fetch API. THe Mozilla documentation is a bit unclear at this point.

As far as I can tell, I can call `fetch()` in one of two ways:

- with two parameters, a url and an init object
- with one parameter, a Request object

However, it appears the Request object simply combines the two parameters. I have tested the following and get the same result:

```js
function object2query(object) {
 var qs=[];
 Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object).forEach(function(i) {
  qs.push(i+'='+object[i]);
 });
 return qs.join('&');
}

var url='https://ajax.internotes.net/date.php';
var query={date: 'today', time: 0, format: 'Y-m-d'};
query=object2query(query);

// Post Method
 var initPost={method: 'post', body: query, headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 }};

// Two Parameters
 fetch(url,initPost)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(function(text) {alert('Two Parameters: '+text)});

// Request Object
 var request=new Request(url,initPost);
 fetch(request)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(function(text) {alert('Request Object: '+text)});
```

If that is the case, what is the benefit of using the Request Object?

Comment: reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) there's a statement that says, *but you are more likely to encounter a Request object being returned as the result of another API operation, such as a service worker FetchEvent.request*